# Format string and fill with elements of array

Tags: python

I've got a string which I want to `format()` with elements of an array (incrementally). Right now, the elements are placed via `.format(*arr)` but I want to run `formatNumbers()` for each element first and have its output placed in the string.

```
def formatNumbers(number):
    return str("{:,}".format(number)).replace(",", " ")

def displayNumbers():
    arr = [ 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 ]
    myString = "Numbers:\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(*arr)
    print(myString)
```

Is there a fast way of doing this? Just writing `.format(formatNumbers(*arr))` doesn't seem to work.
Do I need to make a "temporary array" to store the strings an then use the * operator to iterate through them, or is there an easier way?

Current output:

```
Numbers: 
1000 
2000 
3000 
4000 
5000
```

Desired output (via calling `formatNumbers()`):

```
Numbers: 
1 000
2 000 
3 000 
4 000 
5 000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `map` function to apply another function to every element of a list. In your case, it would look like this:

```py
myString = "Numbers:\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(*map(formatNumbers, arr))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
myString = "Numbers:"+("\n{}" * len(arr)).format(*[formatNumbers(x) for x in arr])
# or
myString = "Numbers:" + "".join(["\n{}".format(formatNumbers(x)) for x in arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to apply function `formatNumbers()` to all elements of `arr`:

```
myString = "Numbers:\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(*map(formatNumbers, arr))
```

And the output will be:

```
Numbers:
1 000
2 000
3 000
4 000
5 000
```

---

Additionally you can replace the multiple `\n` in your formatted string and use `join()` instead:

```
import os


arr = [ 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000 ]
print(f"Numbers: \n{os.linesep.join(map(formatNumbers, arr))}")
```